# Select coefs with an interaction and add value

Tags: r

Given a list of coefficients,

```
> dput(coefs)
structure(c(-0.000543450489419213, 0.293366492387962, 0.00853931616186778, 
0.399449785898867, -0.000393107240288805, 0.504624470243149, 
-0.0103420202744057, 0.00283255134378993), .Names = c("(Intercept)", 
"x", "x2", "tx", "x:x2", "x:tx", "x2:tx", "x:x2:tx"))
```

How can I select all of the interactions and then add a constant to all?

I'm able to select the coefficients and add a constant (e.g., .1) but I how to I merge this with `coefs`?

```
 interactions=grep(':',names(coefs)) #id interactions terms
 coefs.interaction=coefs[interactions]+.1
```

It should return something like:

```
  (Intercept)             x            x2            tx          x:x2          x:tx         x2:tx       x:x2:tx 
-0.0005434505  0.2933664924  0.0085393162  0.3994497859 0.49944979  0.6046244702 0.8965798  0.1028325513
```

Comment: `new_coefs = coefs; new_coefs[interactions] <- new_coefs[interactions] + .1` ?

Comment: @akrun That depends on the ordering the coefs are provided in, and might not extend to coefs returned by all estimation functions (though I really don't know). I was thinking... `coefs + .1*grepl(':',names(coefs))`

Comment: @Frank if you post as answer, I will accept. Otherwise, I will post answer myself.

Comment: Sorry, no access to a computer this week. Go ahead and post it yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I described in my question, `interactions=grep(':',names(coefs))` will identify the location of all of the interactions by selecting coefficients with ":" in them.

Then, as commented by @Frank (with a little more explanation by me), you can do:

```
new_coefs = coefs #duplicate set of coefficients 
new_coefs[interactions] <- new_coefs[interactions] + .1
```

See that `new_coefs[interactions]+1` selects the variables containing an interactions and allows you to add a constant to them.

Then, you can selectively write over the `new_coefs` by setting `new_coefs[interactions]` equal to `new_coefs[interactions] + .1`